# How to declare two paths (endpoints) for the same operation in an OpenAPI file?

Tags: openapi

Query by Example: in OneDrive API, there are several ways to specify an object in one operation - for file upload (check in), the following paths are defined:

- POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/checkin
- POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin
- POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/checkin
- POST/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin
- POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin

Is there a way to describe such paths/endpoints so that there's no duplication in an OpenAPI file? Maybe, one endpoint can be a ref to another? Duplicating all the complex information in five (in the above example) paths seems to be overkill.

The question is merely about an OpenAPI file - the server will handle all path variations by parsing the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really ugly way to do it would be an enum of path parameters on the first resource level

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: a test api
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  "/{grouping}/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/checkin":
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: grouping
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            enum:
              - drives
              - groups
              - sites
              - users
        - name: group-id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: item-id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string         
      requestBody:
        description: an ugly api
        content:
          "application/json":
            schema: {}
            examples:
              groups_checkin_example:
                value: {...}
              users_checkin_example:
                value: {...}
              sites_checkin_example:
                value: {...}
              drives_checkin_example:
                value: {...}
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema: {}
```

There is no way to communicate each permutation of this type of pattern if each of the "groupings" have a different type of identifier pattern. e.g. You can't communicate a `group-id` only applies to the `groups` parameter. If your `groups` id is a uuid and a `sites` id is a simple string, the user will only know by trial and error or documentation provided by you.

This also doesn't cover this use case because the uri pattern doesn't match:
`POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/checkin`

EDIT: answering your other question

You can set the path params as not `required`.  This is a really ugly way to use OpenAPI though. Highly, not recommended.  :)

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: a test api
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  "/{grouping}/{group-id}/{drive}/items/{item-id}/checkin":
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: grouping
          in: path
          schema:
            enum:
              - drives
              - groups
              - sites
              - users
        - name: group-id
          in: path
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: drive
          in: path
          schema:
            type: string
            enum:
              - drive
        - name: item-id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        description: an ugly api
        content:
          "application/json":
            schema: {}
            examples:
              groups_checkin_example:
                value: { ... }
              users_checkin_example:
                value: { ... }
              sites_checkin_example:
                value: { ... }
              drives_checkin_example:
                value: { ... }
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema: {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. This would work for the set of different grouping parameters. What about an optional part, such as "/items/xyz" vs "/drives/ABC/items/xyz"?

Comment: updated the answer.  if it works for you, consider marking the answer accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The editor I am using (Stoplight Studio) claims that path parameters are required if they are present, so I didn't even consider such an aproach.

Comment: that's a customization applied by Stoplight, probably to prevent the behavior I suggested. (Again, it's ugly and not the intention of OAS)   The schema itself does not prevent that behavior though.  [OAS JSON Schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.0/schema.json#L790C4-L800C6)

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like Swagger also requires parameters to be required :(. If I don't specify "required" at all, it complains that there must be a "required" property there. If I add "required: false", Swagger, on the line with "required", gives an error "should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: true" (the text is copied). Maybe, it's Swagger's parser failure, but anyway...

Comment: welp, at least they are preventing it from working.. haha..  if you want to see it work per the actual spec, you can upload the OAS document here.  https://redocly.github.io/redoc

Comment: as you found out, some OAS tooling create their own interpretation of the specification to prevent certain behaviors.